# Where does ARC write the release instructions?

Tags: objective-c, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I know each time I press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on my keyboard:

1. Xcode does wake up ARC
2. ARC analyzes my code and writes all the `retain/release/autorelease` invocations
3. finally the code is compiled by LLVM

A few more things happen in the process, however what I am asking is...

### Where does ARC write the release instructions?

1. Just before the variable that reference an instance of a class goes **out of scope**
2. Just after the last time that variable is **used**

### Example

```
class HugeObject {
    func doVeryImportantStuff() { print("The answer is \((10*4)+2)") }
}

func foo() {
    let a = HugeObject()
    a.doVeryImportantStuff()

    // <-- Point A

    let b = HugeObject()
    b.doVeryImportantStuff()

    // <-- Point B
}
```

Where is ARC going to write the `a.release()` line?

- At `Point B`?
- Or, better, it is able to understand that the `a.release` can safely be moved at `Point A`?

I suspect there could be important implications in terms of footprint but I could not find any information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: ARC is a part of the compiler, whose name is clang, not LLWM. It is done while compiling.

---

To your Q:

Short answer: This depends on the annotations you gave the compiler. Default is not too early and not too late.

Long answer:

Semantically the release of a local var (local scope, auto) is sent, when the extent of the local var is lost. But this is optimized. Therefore it is possible that technically the release is sent earlier, that means between the last visible usage of the local var and the loss of the extent.

If you have a reason to keep the retain as long as the extent, you have to annotate `objc_precise_lifetime`.

> In general, ARC maintains an invariant that a retainable object pointer held in a __strong object will be retained for the full formal lifetime of the object. Objects subject to this invariant have precise lifetime semantics.
>
> By default, local variables of automatic storage duration do not have precise lifetime semantics. Such objects are simply strong references which hold values of retainable object pointer type, and these values are still fully subject to the optimizations on values under local control.
>
> […]
>
> A local variable of retainable object owner type and automatic storage duration may be annotated with the objc_precise_lifetime attribute to indicate that it should be considered to be an object with precise lifetime semantics.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#precise-lifetime-semantics

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a question: you corrected me writing *First of all: ARC is a part of the compiler, whose name is clang, not LLVM.* So if the name of the compiler is **clang** then why on the Apple website I read **Using the incredibly high-performance LLVM compiler, Swift code...** or **The powerful open-source LLVM compiler for C, C++, and Objective-C is built into Xcode and available from Terminal.**? Sources: https://developer.apple.com/swift/ and https://developer.apple.com/xcode/features/

Comment: 1. Do not use Apple's documentation for questions about the compiler (and language.) Always use the documentation of clang. 2. clang is the Objective-C front-end of the LLVM project. So it is an LLVM compiler with the name clang. The version shipped with Xcode always compiles down to machine code. (So it is no pure front-end, but a complete compiler.) 3. Even it does not belong to this subject: Apple's documentation about Swift are simple commercials. They do all to make Swift popular including making Objective-C worse. Until nowadays they failed. But I'm sure Apple will do more.